# python manage.py runserver keeps reloading stating file has changed

Tags: python, django

I've been working on a django project with no issues. I've pulled updated code from the remote repository and now if i do `python manage.py runserver` in cmd, i keep getting error

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
D:\some_project\someapp\schemes\models.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...
```

then

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
D:\some_project\someapp\schemes\views.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...
```

it keeps looping through all the files and all the apps that have in my django project. 
it works if i try `python manage.py runserver --noreload` however, i'm curious as to what lead to the issue in the first place.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem. I was using Vagrant and it was working fine, but just after adding a new app to my Django project, the problem emerged. Have you found any clue yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be experiencing this issue due to your development environment. If you are using a Vagrant server or similar, the reloading of the files would be due to the Vagrant server refreshing the files from your local machine.

The `--noreload` flag is suitable for situations like this.

Answer (score 1):

I just restart the server and VScode then it's worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).