# Django Rest Framework - Account Verification Email: send_mail() works in console but not using SMTP

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, gmail, user-registration

I have looked around StackOverflow and other places but I am not able to find a solution to my problem. I am using Django Rest Framework and Django Knox for user authentication and I want to send an account verification email to newly registered users. I am using Gmail.

My email settings in my settings.py file are as below:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
# EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend' #Using this for testing
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_PORT = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PORT')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
```

When I use `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'`, I am able to see the email printed on the server. However when I use `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'`, I don't get the email every time. **I have to try sending an email multiple times to receive 1 email.** Because I am receiving emails a few times, I think my credentials are right. I don't see any errors printed on the server either. Is this a Gmail issue considering I am receiving emails sometimes?

An additional thing I noticed while working on this was that any code **after** `send_mail` is not executed in my API view. I am using a custom user model and my Register API View is below.

```
class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        employee = serializer.save()

        uidb64=urlsafe_base64_encode(smart_bytes(employee.id))
        token=default_token_generator.make_token(user=employee)
        email_body='Click on the link below to activate your account\nhttp://127.0.0.1:8000/'+uidb64+'/'+token

        send_mail('Activate your EmployeeDev Account', email_body, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [employee.email], fail_silently=False)

        return Response({
            "employee": EmployeeSerializer(employee, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(employee)[1]
        })
```

I am able to register a new user if I comment out the `send_mail` line in my Register API. I also get a 200 response back with the employee information and token. With the `send_mail` line, I get no response back and it looks like any code after send_mail is not executed (in this case the `return Response` statement). I also tried creating a separate function for `send_mail` but it did not make a difference.

As soon as `send_mail` is called, the server prints "db.sqlite3 changed, reloading" without returning the `Response`.

My Register Serializer is as below.

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'password', 'employee_number', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'department_name')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        employee = Employee.objects.create_user(
            validated_data['email'],
            validated_data['password'],
            validated_data['first_name'],
            validated_data['last_name'],
            validated_data['employee_number'],
            validated_data['department_name']
        )
        return employee
```

**Edit**
I added `'before'` and `'after'` print statements to my post function as shown below.

```
class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        employee = serializer.save()

        employee_data=serializer.data
        uidb64=urlsafe_base64_encode(smart_bytes(employee_data['id']))
        token=default_token_generator.make_token(user=employee)
        email_subject="Activate your EmployeeDev Account"
        email_body='http://127.0.0.1:8080/?uidb='+uidb64+'&token='+token

        print('\n\nbefore\n\n')
        send_mail(email_subject, email_body, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [employee_data['email'],])
        print('\n\nafter\n\n')
            
        return Response({
            "employee": EmployeeSerializer(employee, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(employee)[1]
        })
```

When I use `"django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"` the server shows the following:
[image: Django SMTP Email Server log]

It does not execute any code after `send_mail()`. I also don't get the return Response. I receive the email at times but not every time.
[image: Django SMTP Email - Postman no response]

But if I use `'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'`. I get the following.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This random behaviour to get an email make me think an [email greylisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting_(email)). Have you try with another mail provider ?

For send mail, it can by a blocking request : smtp call is longer than the http current request time to live, so the request fail before le smtp call end. Try to reduce the [email_timeout](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-EMAIL_TIMEOUT) value.

Comment: I also tried it with Outlook and I got the same result. I tried changing the timeout value and I was still getting emails sporadically and not all the time. Just to make sure I am understanding it right, I added print statements before and after the `send_mail()` function. It printed the statement before `send_mail()`, but then reloaded the server without executing the rest of the code after `send_mail()`

Comment: Outlook is mail client :) Try another [mail provider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailbox_provider) : the idea is to exclude a possible problem with your own SMTP server.

What value have you given to EMAIL_TIMEOUT ? The server reload himself during a POST request, without any error message ? Thats very strange. Can you post the server log please ?

Comment: I haven't tried any other mail provider yet. Regarding EMAIL_TIMEOUT, I started out with the default: None. I changed it to a whole bunch of values between 2 and 300 seconds. I have added some more relevant information to my original question like the response I get back. Let me know if I'm missing something

Comment: EMAIL_TIMEOUT should be < 30 I think. More an the HTTP may timeout (depending on the client)
the `db.sqlite3 changed, reloading` message is very strange. I think another program edit this file, causing the server to reload (even if only python should be tracked for a reload). Is your api launched twice ? or maybe a database explorer is opened on your sqlite file ?
Try to use [--noreload flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61007749/python-manage-py-runserver-keeps-reloading-stating-file-has-changed) to see if the request fail because of the reload.